# Cauchy in measure iff Cauchy a.e.

Tags: measure-theory

I was wondering if this is true since I haven't seen anything about it in Folland.

Let $(X,M, \mu)$ be a measure space

Cauchy a.e. clearly implies Cauchy in measure.

To show the other direction. assume that a sequence of measurable functions $\{f_n\}$ is not Cauchy a.e.  Then there exists a set $E\in M$ such that $\mu(E)>0$ and $\{f_n\}$ is not Cauchy on $E$.

We can decompose $E$ into a countable union: $E=\cup_{n_0=1}^\infty \cup_{N\in\mathbb{N}} \cap_{n,m\geq N} \{x :|{f_n(x)-f_m(x)}|\geq \frac{1}{n_0}\}$

Since $E$ has positive measure, then one if its the sets $\cup_{N\in\mathbb{N}} \cap_{n,m\geq N} \{x :|{f_n(x)-f_m(x)}|\geq \frac{1}{n_0}\}$ must have have positive measure, and thus on this set the $\{f_n\}$ is not Cauchy in measure.

Is my proof correct? Can I just replace "Cauchy in measure" with "Cauchy a.e."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cauchy a.e. clearly implies Cauchy in measure." is false. It's only true when $\mu(X)<\infty$, and it's not so clear. Consider the sequence of functions $\chi_{[n,\infty)}$, which converges everywhere, but is not Cauchy in measure.

Your presentation of $E$ isn't quite right: Not Cauchy $\Leftrightarrow \exists \epsilon, \forall N, \exists m, n, \cdots$, and $\exists$ should translate to $\cup$ while $\forall$ should translate to $\cap$. So it should be $\cup\cap\cup$.

This direction is also false. To construct a counter example, let $f_{n,i}$ be the characteristic function of the interval $[\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i+1}{2^n}]$ for $i=0, 1, \cdots, 2^n-1$. And list them in a single sequence: $f_{1, 0}, f_{1,1}, f_{2, 0}, f_{2, 1}, f_{2,2}, f_{2,3}, f_{3, 0}, f_{3, 1}, f_{3, 2}, \cdots$, then this sequence clearly converges to $0$ in measure, but it diverges everywhere on $(0, 1)$.

The best you can hope for this direction is that there exists a subsequence of $f_n$ that converges a.e.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed response!